# Test for Broken Links is not working in testNG using Selenium

Tags: hyperlink, testng

Below is the test that will run in Selenium but will not when converted to testNG.  When run in testNG is does not show any test being run. Appreciate any help.

Thanks,

```java
public class Links_on_login_page {
        
    @Test
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();        
        driver.get("https://gmail.com");        
        List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));        
        System.out.println("Total links are "+links.size());        
        for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
        {           
            WebElement ele= links.get(i);           
            String url=ele.getAttribute("href");            
            verifyLinkActive(url);          
        }
            }   
    public static void verifyLinkActive(String linkUrl)
    {
        try 
        {
           URL url = new URL(linkUrl);           
           HttpURLConnection httpURLConnect=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();           
           httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000);
           httpURLConnect.connect();           
           if(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode()==200)
           {
               System.out.println(linkUrl+" - "+httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage());
            }
          if(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND)  
           {
               System.out.println(linkUrl+" - "+httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage() + " - "+ HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: remove static modifier from method signature and also remove parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comment,need to update method name under @Test. also add path to chromedriver.exe. for testng refer https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

```
    @Test
    public void brokenURLsTest()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\mural\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();        
        driver.get("https://gmail.com");        
        List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));        
        System.out.println("Total links are "+links.size());        
        for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
        {           
            WebElement ele= links.get(i);           
            String url=ele.getAttribute("href");            
            verifyLinkActive(url);          
        }
            }   
    public static void verifyLinkActive(String linkUrl)
    {
        try 
        {
           URL url = new URL(linkUrl);           
           HttpURLConnection httpURLConnect=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();           
           httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000);
           httpURLConnect.connect();           
           if(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode()==200)
           {
               System.out.println(linkUrl+" - "+httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage());
            }
          if(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND)  
           {
               System.out.println(linkUrl+" - "+httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage() + " - "+ HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           
        }
    }
```